# AzDo to pull into 2 different remote/target branches at same time

Tags: azure-devops

We have 2 branches:

- Master
- Development

`Development` is always equated to `Master` and deployed until the Non-Prd environment and features are based on the `Development` branch.
So, when there is a bug and needed to fix in PRD, then we create a new branch out of the `Master` and call it as `Hotfix`. and once it's tested, we merge it into `Master` and rolled out to PRD as any other process, and at the same time, we also merge into Development, so that the feature branches has this feature. But quite recently we noticed that sometimes after the hotfix and merge to `Master`, we forget to merge into  `Development`, which later stage causing big issues in conflicts and so not. So, my question is there anyway, in AzDo pipeline that with a click of one button it will merge into both `Master` and `Development`? not a button but in an Automated way so, AzDo will trigger auto merging in both branches and this manual error can be fixed.

Added my thoughts:(it's kind of like Start a pull request for multiple target branches)
Something like this, whenever final pull requests will be done, then if the branch is Hotfix* then pull will always show like this:

[image]

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue?  Feel free to let me know if you're still blocked, I'll try my best to help :)

Comment: Hey @WalterQian-MSFT thanks for following up and checking. I really appreciate it. I can not add `gitmerge`  task in my pipeline as I don't have the right to add this task because of my company policy. But is there any other way we can work this out? I have updated my initial question what is in my mind....

Comment: Each pull request can only have 1 target branch. We can use [create pull request rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#examples) and create two pull requests in the pipeline. If this way meets your needs, I will update my answer according to it.

Comment: @WalterQian-MSFT looking forward to your answer.

Comment: I don't think, you should update your answer, instead add a new one. I might not have the right to add extra tasks from the marketplace but someone else might have and the solution which you earlier present is quite elegant and maybe that someone else can use it.

Comment: Please check my update. If you use the new way, new pull requests will be created after running pipeline. If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you want to merge branches in Azure Pipeline, you can try to use
  git merge task. You can find this task in the marketplace. Please
  note that you need to use a **self-hosted** agent.
- Since you mentioned that you want a button to decide whether to merge
  to master and development branches, I suggest you can add parameters
  in your yaml file.

Here is my sample:

```
pool: Default
parameters:
  - name: MergeToMaster
    type: boolean
    default: false
  - name: MergeToDevelopment
    type: boolean
    default: false

jobs:
- job: MergeToMaster
  condition: eq(${{parameters.MergeToMaster}}, 'true')
  steps:
  - task: gitMerge@0
    inputs:
      mergeType: 'merge'
      targetBranch: 'master'
      repoUrl: 'https://{Organization} @dev.azure.com/{Organization}/{Project} /_git/{repo name}'
      remoteName: 'origin'
      pat: '{PAT}'


- job: MergeToDevelopment
  condition: eq(${{parameters.MergeToDevelopment}}, 'true')
  steps:
  - task: gitMerge@0
    inputs:
      mergeType: 'merge'
      targetBranch: 'Development'
      repoUrl: 'https://{Organization} @dev.azure.com/{Organization}/{Project} /_git/{repo name}'
      remoteName: 'origin'
      pat: '{PAT}'
```

You can see two options when you run pipelines. Selecting the option will merge to the corresponding branches.

[image]

**Update:**

You can use [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to create pull request to master and development branches. Please use powershell task to replace git merger task. Here is my sample:

```
jobs:
- job: CreatePRToMaster
  condition: eq(${{parameters.MergeToMaster}}, 'true')
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        $url = "https://dev.azure.com/{Organization name}/{Project name}/_apis/git/repositories/{Repo ID}/pullrequests?api-version=6.1-preview.1"
        $contentType = "application/json"
        $user="user"
        $token="{PAT}"
        $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
        $body= @'
        {
          "sourceRefName": "refs/heads/hotfix",
          "targetRefName": "refs/heads/master",
          "title": "test",
          "description": "test"
        }
        '@
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -ContentType $contentType -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Body $body


- job: CreatePRToDevelopment
  condition: eq(${{parameters.MergeToDevelopment}}, 'true')
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        $url = "https://dev.azure.com/{Organization name}/{Project name}/_apis/git/repositories/{Repo ID}/pullrequests?api-version=6.1-preview.1"
        $contentType = "application/json"
        $user="user"
        $token="{PAT}"
        $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
        $body= @'
        {
          "sourceRefName": "refs/heads/hotfix",
          "targetRefName": "refs/heads/Development",
          "title": "test",
          "description": "test"
        }
        '@
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -ContentType $contentType -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Body $body
```

Selecting the options when you run pipeline will create pull requests to the corresponding branches.
Result:

[image]

Comment: @change198 You can test this example on your side. If you have any concern, feel free to share it here. If it can solve your problem, you could accept it as answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thank you.

Comment: definitely.....I will update and post my findings here. thanks again.

Comment: I have added one more condition in my scenario `condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')`

Comment: I tried to replicate your suggestion using bash also instead of using basic header authorization using PAT of the user I'm using Bearer $(System.AccessToken). Now I'm getting 400 error. May be if it's not too much can I ask to have a look and let me know, if something I missed. `curl -d '{"sourceRefName": $(BUILD.SOURCEBRANCH), "targetRefName": "refs/heads/devlopment", "title": "test",  "description": "test" }' -X POST -H "Authorization:Bearer $(System.AccessToken)" -H "Content-Type:application/json"  ${url} --write-out "%{http_code}" --output response.json` see next comments

Comment: Url is the normal url and I'm following `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0` as a guide.

Comment: I accepted this as an answer...thanks a lot. this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

It somewhat appears like you are using the GitFlow branch strategy.  You could consider using some custom scripts or extensions to manage this.  If you wanted to leverage [Git-Flow extension](http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/#setup), when you [finish a hotfix](http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/#hotfixes) it would do those two merges for you.

```
git flow hotfix finish VERSION
```

[image]

If you are using Visual Studio, you could also use the [GitFlow for Visual Studio 2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-57624.GitFlowforVisualStudio2019) which when "finishing" the hotfix should do both merges.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, and it kind of loosely based on the concept GitFlow branch strategy. Let me explore the possibility of the same in AzDo.